# How to place NS from Google Cloud in Namecheap?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, namecheap

My web app is on Google Cloud. I have the following NS on Google Cloud:
[image]

I followed this tutorial to setup dns: https://www.wpmentor.com/setup-domain-google-cloud-platform/ I'm using Namecheap.

Under step 3 Configure Name Server, there are some differences. Nameservers can be found on the "Advanced DNS" section instead of the "Domain" section like in this older tutorial. There is nothing about nameservers in the "Domain" section, so it's probably moved to "Advanced DNS".
[image]
But when I want to insert my NS in the "Advanced DNS" section, it asks me to provide IP addresses. I'm confused, should I find somewhere an IP address of `ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com.` somewhere?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have the Namecheap permission **Manage Private Nameservers**? Edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

To connect a domain to a third-party server via nameservers that you received from your hosting provider, you need to set these nameservers as Custom for your domain as mentioned by **@John Hanley**. You can do that in the following way:

1. After signing into your account, select the **Domain** tab and click the **Manage** button next to your domain in the list. Then find the **Nameservers** section and select **Custom DNS** from the drop-down menu.
2. After that, enter your hosting nameservers one by one in each line (if you need to set more than 2 nameservers, press the **Add nameserver**). When the nameservers are entered, save changes.

It may take about 24-48 hours for your domain to propagate after the nameservers update to be resolving properly all over the world.

**NOTE:** Some hosting providers may provide you with nameservers with IP addresses for them. Entering **nameservers** would be enough.

Refer [How to Connect a Domain to a Server or Hosting](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9837/46/how-to-connect-a-domain-to-a-server-or-hosting/) for information.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't have"Nameservers" when I scroll down, you can see in my first screenshot